# How to subscribe visp_auto_tracker to /usb_cam/image_raw/compressed?

Tags: compressed-image-transport, camera, image-raw, visp-auto-tracker, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am wondering if this is possible, since just subscribing to /usb_cam/image_raw causes a lot of lag, and the visp_auto_tracker debug display window will freeze up. Here is my launch file to run visp_auto_tracker (where I try to subscribe to /usb_cam/image_raw/compressed):

```
<launch>
  <!-- Launch the tracking node -->
  <node pkg="visp_auto_tracker" type="visp_auto_tracker" name="visp_auto_tracker" output="screen">
    <param name="model_path" type="string" value="$(find visp_auto_tracker)/models" />
    <param name="model_name" type="string" value="pattern" />
    <param name="debug_display" type="bool" value="True" />

    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/camera_info" to="/usb_cam/camera_info"/>
    <remap from="/visp_auto_tracker/image_raw" to="/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

But when I run this, I get this error in the terminal where I am running the usb_cam node:

```
[ERROR] [1405534682.215726942]: Client [/visp_auto_tracker] wants topic /usb_cam/image_raw/compressed to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743], but our version has [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage/8f7a12909da2c9d3332d540a0977563f]. Dropping connection.
```

So, is there a way to properly subscribe the visp_auto_tracker to /usb_cam/image_raw/compression? Appreciate any help, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186842/how-to-subscribe-visp_auto_tracker-to-/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed?/) by [Alvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/18825/alvin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2014-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please post relevant code. There is a type mismatch. The topic is posting the message with a particular data-type and you are subscribing to another data-type.

I think the topic by-default uses [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CompressedImage.html) while your callback has type [sensor_msgs/Image](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html).

If your callback has arguments

`const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& _msg`

change that to

`const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr& _msg`

But, of course, you should change the code inside the callback to be sure you are doing the right things with that message.

If you are using a default ros executable and then using that remap, it won't work at all. Because the topic types are different.

Have a great day!

`

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvin](https://answers.ros.org/users/18825/alvin/) on 2014-07-18**:
Thank you for the response! Currently, I am not running any code, just rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node and visp_auto_tracker via the above launch file...so I'm not sure where I can do the changes as you suggested.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-19**:
That means you mus provide the topic that the node you are running requires. So remove the remaps. They won't work.